# Grails REST API with two controllers

Tags: rest, grails

I have a problem and couldn't find any concrete tutorials about defining a domain class (e.g. Person) as uri resource but using the dependent controller (e.g. PersonController) for rendering pages and a restful controller using this domain class just for API Requests.

Can anybody give me an advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You just have to define a restful controller and remove the resource uris in the domain class.

Comment: just in case: it's better to provide example code in questions and answers.